# Is it possible to have multiple domain which point to a server with different ports?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I have a server, running multiple instance of tornado web sites on different ports. for example:
127.0.0.1:8000
127.0.0.1:8001
127.0.0.1:8002

Is it possible to assign each one a domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use DNS to map port numbers (except for `SRV` records, but that doesn't apply here).  What you could do is to put up a reverse proxy in front of those services that forward the requests to different other hosts and ports depending on the host name in the HTTP request.